# How to select the option preferred country/region website from the dropdown listbox within using Selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to select the option preferred country/region website Turkey from the dropdown listbox within https://www.amazon.com/customer-preferences/country/?ref_=nav_em_locale_0_1_1_37  using Selenium in Java?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdJz.png)

I didn't find id and name when i try to find from inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the **class = a-icon a-icon-dropdown** . In selenium you can also use the class if I am not mistaken, you just have to be careful because sometimes they use the same class for different objects.

Comment: Thank you. amazon is hard for me just now. I am the new to automation testing